# How embed a crystal report in vb .net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have created a Crystal report in a vb .net app that works perfectly on my development machine.  However, in order for the reports to work correctly on user machines I must create an extra folder that contains the .rpt file.  My question is, how can I embed the report so that it is contained in the .exe ?

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub PreviewPickList(ByVal PickListNo As Integer, Optional ByVal ShopOrderId As Integer = 0)
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument
    cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Inventory\PickListReportCR.rpt")
    PickListViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt

    Dim dtPickList As New DataTable
    dtPickList = DTEngines.GetPickList(PickListNo, ShopOrderId)

    cryRpt.SetDataSource(dtPickList)
    PickListViewer.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None
    PickListViewer.Refresh()
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

It is obvious to me that the cryRpt.load line is specifying a specific path, but when I change it to something like:

```
cryRpt.Load("PickListReportCR.rtp")
```

or

```
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\PickListReportCR.rpt")
```

Neither option works.

I have already set the properties to "Embedded Resource" and "Do not Copy"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Google found me [**this**](http://www.it-sideways.com/2011/02/deploy-crystal-report-rpt-files.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
dim doc as new ReportDocument
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("PickListReportCR.rpt"))
doc.SetDatabaseLogon(ReportServerDSUserName, ReportServerDSPassword,ReportServerDomain, "DatabseName", false)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
```

Try this...

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this answer.  I assumed I would receive an email notification, but did not so I assumed that nobody had an answer for me.  The customer requirements changed and I never had to implement, so I don't know if your solution worked.  Thanks again for the answer.